# Drawing a cantor set with Graphics.py

Tags: python-3.x, graphics

I'm trying to draw a cantor set on a graphical window using lines in python.
What I have so far is

```
from graphics import *

def cantor_set(win,x,y,h,Len): 

    if Len < 2: return

    line = Line(Point(x, y), Point(x+Len, y))
    line.setWidth(10)
    line.draw(win)

    cantor_set(win,x,y+h,h,Len//3)
    cantor_set(win,x+Len*(2//3),y+h,h,Len//3)

def cantor_set_starter():
    win = GraphWin("Cantor Set", 500, 250)
    cantor_set(win,5,10,20,490)

cantor_set_starter()
```

But running this returns

[image: Cantor Set Crash]

And then the window crashes with no error and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it with this

```
from graphics import *

def cantor_set(win,x,y,h,Len): 

    if Len < 2: return

    line = Line(Point(x, y), Point(x+Len, y))
    line.setWidth(10)
    line.draw(win)

    cantor_set(win,x,y+h,h,Len//3)
    cantor_set(win,x+Len*2//3,y+h,h,Len//3)

def cantor_set_starter():
    Len = 490
    win = GraphWin("Cantor Set", 500, 250)
    cantor_set(win,5,10,20,490)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

cantor_set_starter()
```

It seems the math was bad on the second recursion and adding a .getmouse() and a .close() fixed the crash